# creating a slack bot using slack-api ruby gem not responding back as a DM

Tags: ruby, slack-api

I have set up a slack bot using `slack-api` and the real-time-messaging api.

Here is the abbreviated setup:

```
client.on :message do |data|
  d {data}
  bot_response = BotResponse.get_bot_response(data['text'], "session_slack")
  Slack.chat_postMessage channel: data['user'], text: "#{bot_response}"
end

client.start
```

With this version of the postMessage, the response comes from Slackbot, not my bot (named kaya).

**Goal: I want to respond to come as a DM from the bot it was sent to.**

When I change the channel to data['channel'], the response comes as DM from my bot kaya, but gets into an endless loop.

**How do I have a non-endless loop DM response?**

**NOTE:**
I think I see how it is happening: by selecting the bot as the "channel" the bot is responding to it's own response back to me, as if it were another user talking into the "bot's" channel.  But I can't tell how else to have the response come from my bot, not slackbot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include the `username` parameter set to the bot name per the api: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage, or you need the `as_user` option.

Comment: Yeah I added it. It still puts it elsewhere but correctly had he name. It seems that my boy takes its own responses as input. So something about DM from a bot seems off.

Answer (score 0):

This mixes the Web and the RealTime Messaging API. You get a message from the RealTime Messaging API then you are using the Web API to post back. The answer of including `as_user: true` is correct, but you should instead use the RTM API to send the message back.

Try https://github.com/dblock/slack-ruby-client instead that cleanly separates the two. Sending a message back as the bot looks like this:

`client.message channel: data['channel'], text: "Hi <@#{data['user']}>!"`

To avoid DM loops, make sure you're not responding to commands that you emit. There're other ways, like ignoring bot messages, but it's not as reliable.